# Procedure of executing in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I have following piece of code:

```
let p = print_string("finished\n");;

let x0 = ref 0;;

class point =
  object
    val mutable x = incr x0; !x0
    method get_x = x
    method move d = x <- x + d
  end
;;

print_int(new point#get_x);;
p;;
print_int(new point#get_x);;
p;;
```

Can't understand why the output is:

```
finished
12
```

My expectation is actually like:

```
1
finished
2
finished
```

Anyone can tell what's the correct order of executing this piece of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main point of confusion is that your `p` isn't a function. It's just a value. In particular, it is the value `()` (known as unit). So when you evaluate `p` later in your code it has no effect. All the work was done when p was created.

If you want p to act like a function (which is what you seem to want), you should define it like this:

```
let p () = print_string "finished\n";;
```

And you should call it like this:

```
p ();;
```